# Import fails with "The import/export profile with id x can only be used for import"

Tags: shopware6

We did a product Import with a profile which is only marked as "import" in Shopware 6.5.2.1

Still we get the message

```
The import/export profile with id x can only be used for import
```

In the message consumer while the import is stuck on processing.
We have an error (duplicate productNumber in the file) - but this is not properly reported in the case the profile is set only to "import".

Is this normal behavior or a bug?

We assume that Shopware internally tries to also export the data, to use it for the error report?

Remark: The question is not about the above mentioned error in the import file - we know we can fix the "duplicate product number" problem by setting the matching column to `productNumber` instead of `id`.

Answer (score 1):

> We assume that Shopware internally tries to also export the data, to use it for the error report?

[Yes, that's it.](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/0bc4296f58d8937271e606b31641a7f7f9db6b99/src/Core/Content/ImportExport/ImportExport.php#L426) I think this can be considered a bug, could you report it please?

If it's urgent you can patch it for the time being:

```
diff --git a/src/Core/Content/ImportExport/Service/ImportExportService.php b/src/Core/Content/ImportExport/Service/ImportExportService.php
--- a/src/Core/Content/ImportExport/Service/ImportExportService.php (revision d832807a8e3a4e7e4cfc922e18fdf7bb8d386ac9)
+++ b/src/Core/Content/ImportExport/Service/ImportExportService.php (date 1687804790920)
@@ -51,7 +51,10 @@
     ): ImportExportLogEntity {
         $profileEntity = $this->findProfile($context, $profileId);
 
-        if (!\in_array($profileEntity->getType(), [ImportExportProfileEntity::TYPE_EXPORT, ImportExportProfileEntity::TYPE_IMPORT_EXPORT], true)) {
+        if (
+            !\in_array($profileEntity->getType(), [ImportExportProfileEntity::TYPE_EXPORT, ImportExportProfileEntity::TYPE_IMPORT_EXPORT], true)
+            && $activity !== ImportExportLogEntity::ACTIVITY_INVALID_RECORDS_EXPORT
+        ) {
             throw new ProfileWrongTypeException($profileEntity->getId(), $profileEntity->getType());
         }
```

Comment: Not urgent though - as workaround we are able to markt it as export/import profile. But thanks for the patch
Reported: https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-28857